# Does anyone know how to apply RTL to the plugin mmenu.js?

Tags: jquery, css, mmenu

I've been trying to add **dir="rtl"** to the main nav in html
but it doesn't work properly.

So I think I should do it in the mmenu.css but I don't know how to implement it
Any suggestion

Comment: I'm still looking for the answer please if someone know the answer let me know

Comment: First off avoid jQuery like the plague. Secondly on this site you need to post what the specific problem is and what you've tried. I won't down-vote or vote to close because you're new though there are trolls on here that do that without making any attempt to help. Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As John pointed out, you are required to show what you've tried and what isn't working. Stack Overflow isn't a free coding service. I won't down vote this question, but I did vote to close since there is no code here and you are asking for developer help. If this question gets updated with specific code and what you've tried, I'll retract my close vote.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. This doesn't help us at all. You need to post the HTML/CSS you are working with. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just add `direction: rtl` to your menu all you need to do is add direction to your html or body, when you do that the plugin will automatically add the style `[dir=rtl] .mm-menu {direction: rtl;}`.
If you want to position your menu to open from right then you can achieve this by using mmenu.js Positioning Extension. The plugin itself has some options for this. Check this link :
https://mmenujs.com/docs/extensions/positioning.html